# Confused by template and URI settings for multi-lingual sites

Tags: localization, craft3

I have 2 x sites with base URLs set to `@web/en/` and `@web/de/`

For client entries in a "Clients" section, I have a template at `templates/clients/_entry.twig` which I want to use for both sites.

What should the Entry URI Format be set to in the Clients section... eg should it be `clients/{slug}` for both sites? Or should the base url be included in these dynamically somehow?

(New to localisation so please excuse me if I'm doing this totally wrong!)

---

UPDATE: if I set the URI to `clients/{slug}` and view `en/clients/clientname` I get this error...

> Warning: chdir(): No such file or directory (errno 2) in
>   /Users/jamesgreig/.composer/vendor/laravel/valet/server.php on line
>   145
>
> Warning:
>   require(/Users/jamesgreig/Repos/hoskins-craft/web/en/index.php):
>   failed to open stream: No such file or directory in
>   /Users/jamesgreig/.composer/vendor/laravel/valet/server.php on line
>   147
>
> Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required
>   '/Users/jamesgreig/Repos/hoskins-craft/web/en/index.php'
>   (include_path='.:/usr/local/Cellar/php@7.1/7.1.16/share/pear') in
>   /Users/jamesgreig/.composer/vendor/laravel/valet/server.php on line
>   147

Comment: Did you create the `en` and `de` folders, and place an index file in both? Because that's what Valet is warning you about. You should have two folders, each with their own index file, and then use define('CRAFT_LOCALE', 'en') and define('CRAFT_LOCALE', 'de') to tell Craft which locale to use for that site (or, if it's Craft 3, I think the constant is CRAFT_SITE).

Comment: Ah I missed that! So now I get....

`Notice: Use of undefined constant CRAFT_BASE_PATH - assumed 'CRAFT_BASE_PATH' in /Users/jamesgreig/Repos/hoskins-craft/web/en/index.php on line 8

Warning: require_once(CRAFT_BASE_PATH/vendor/autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /Users/jamesgreig/Repos/hoskins-craft/web/en/index.php on line 11

Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required 'CRAFT_BASE_PATH/vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='.:/usr/local/Cellar/php@7.1/7.1.16/share/pear') in /Users/jamesgreig/Repos/hoskins-craft/web/en/index.php on line 11`